# How can I optimize multiple conditional database calls in EF Core to fill multiple lists

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am in a bit of a bind, I am a student that has taken a liking to C#/.NET Core and love to work on my hobby project with it. But I have trouble finding a solution for my current problem and I am not sure how to fix it.

In .NET Core I want to show the top 10 statistics about racing drivers in my motorsport database. To be more precisise, I have a relational database with a table named "DriverResults" which holds all the racing results of all the drivers, "DriverResults" holds a Foreign Key to "SeasonDriver" which is a table containing information about a driver for that specific season and lastly "SeasonDriver" contains a Foreign Key to the "Driver" table which contains who the driver is. I want to make a leaderlist with how often one certain driver has won a race, for example.

The leaderlistsModel is the ViewModel for the page and contains 5 Lists with each List containing a Driver object and an int for a calculated statistic. To acquire those the Controller of the leaderlist calls a method to get those leaderlists, the method goes like this:

```
LeaderlistsModel leaderlistsModel = new LeaderlistsModel();

var drivers = DataContext.DriverResults
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .Where(dr => dr.Race.Season.Championship.ActiveChampionship)
    .GroupBy(sd => sd.SeasonDriver.Driver);
```

I wasn't sure how I could work this out in a single LINQ-query after so to fill each of these 5 lists in LeaderlistsModel I make a different call from the var drivers I made, so we got these 5 queries coming:

```
leaderlistsModel.LeaderlistWins = drivers
                .Select(dr => new LeaderlistWin
                {
                    Driver = dr.Key,
                    WinCount = dr.Sum(s => s.Position == 1 ? 1 : 0),
                })
                .OrderByDescending(dr => dr.WinCount)
                .Take(10);

            leaderlistsModel.LeaderlistPodiums = drivers
                .Select(dr => new LeaderlistPodium
                {
                    Driver = dr.Key,
                    PodiumCount = dr.Sum(s => s.Position <= 3 ? 1 : 0),
                })
                .OrderByDescending(dr => dr.PodiumCount)
                .Take(10);

            leaderlistsModel.LeaderlistStarts = drivers
                .Select(dr => new LeaderlistStart
                {
                    Driver = dr.Key,
                    StartCount = dr.Count(),
                })
                .OrderByDescending(dr => dr.StartCount)
                .Take(10);

            leaderlistsModel.LeaderlistNonFinishes = drivers
                .Select(dr => new LeaderlistNonFinish
                {
                    Driver = dr.Key,
                    NonFinishCount = dr.Sum(s => s.Status == Status.DNF || s.Status == Status.DSQ ? 1 : 0),
                })
                .OrderByDescending(dr => dr.NonFinishCount)
                .Take(10);

            leaderlistsModel.LeaderlistPoles = drivers
                .Select(dr => new LeaderlistPole
                {
                    Driver = dr.Key,
                    PoleCount = dr.Sum(s => s.Grid == 1 ? 1 : 0),
                })
                .OrderByDescending(dr => dr.PoleCount)
                .Take(10);
```

Each of these queries take 23 seconds to complete so the whole page takes around 150 seconds to load, which is very long for something that should just be five simple leaderlists.

So my question is how can I make it so that I can calculate and get these statistics about the results of a driver but then not having it cost an incredibly long time to load?

For further reference, the page I ultimately want to show looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy0v9.png)

Thanks for reading this and I hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are pulling the entire dataset 5 times into memory. If I got my analysis correct then it could be more efficient to retrieve it only once, by adding a `.ToList()` after the query definition:

```
var drivers = DataContext.DriverResults
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .Where(dr => dr.Race.Season.Championship.ActiveChampionship)
    .GroupBy(sd => sd.SeasonDriver.Driver)
    .ToList();
```

This results in a collection in memory, which is then operated on 5 times in the subsequent statements.

Also a note: older EF Core versions (I believe up until v2.x) are inefficient when using `GroupBy`. The best way to do a SQL `GROUP BY` is in the database (server-side), but initial EF Core versions have no support for that and will do it in .NET memory instead. If this applies then try to upgrade your program to .NET Core 3.1 + EF Core 3.1.

Comment: Just adding the .ToList() there indeed fixed my whole performance issue, thanks a lot! You are also correct in that I am using EF Core v2 still, I just noticed it does state a warning in the console about GroupBy being evaluated locally so I am going to upgrade that too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how large your table `DriverResults` is but if you have access to SQL Server Management Studio and can run queries, run your query and include Execution Plan. Then look at the Execution Plan and see if it suggests any indexes. I had similar situations where single index would cut 25 secs query down to under 1 second. This is especially true where you have inner joins to get to the `ActiveChampionship`

`ToList()` will pull all records into memory, so this is fine if you have smaller datasets. Once it starts to slow down you might have to write a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Top10Results
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempDriver AS TABLE
    (
        Driver NVARCHAR(50) not null,
        Position INT,
        Status NCHAR(3),
        Grid INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Eddie Cheever', 1, 'FIN', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Eddie Cheever', 2, 'FIN', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Eddie Cheever', 1, 'FIN', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Eddie Cheever', 30, 'DNF', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Alan Prost', 2, 'FIN', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Alan Prost', 1, 'FIN', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Alan Prost', 2, 'FIN', 1);
    INSERT INTO @tempDriver (Driver, Position, Status, Grid)
        VALUES('Alan Prost', 3, 'FIN', 1);

    SELECT Driver, SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WinCount
    FROM @tempDriver
    GROUP BY Driver
    ORDER BY WinCount DESC

    SELECT Driver, SUM(CASE WHEN Position <= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PodiumCount
    FROM @tempDriver
    GROUP BY Driver
    ORDER BY PodiumCount DESC
END
GO

EXECUTE dbo.Top10Results

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Top10Results
GO
```

Your queries would of course be more complex but this is just an example.

Best of luck!